# Jquery not working on php echo html

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a bootstrap carousel that is generated through php , I would like to add caption text outside the carousel and I am following this : 
https://codepen.io/RetinaInc/pen/GJbpB

However, Jquery is not working .. after some search I found out that jquery would not work on html that was echoed with php

```
$("#slider").on('slide.bs.carousel', function(evt) {

  var step = $(evt.relatedTarget).index();

  $('#slider_captions .carousel-caption:not(#caption-' + step + ')').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $('#caption-' + step).fadeIn();
  });

});
```

What is another way that I can use to add this jquery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: so are you trying to echo this?  if it is created dynamically, it is all about the sequence.  you may need to reinitialize your carousel after echoing it but it is plenty possible to dynamically create javascript or jquery.

Comment: does a dynamically created jquery work?

Comment: sure it does, but it will need to be re-initialized unless it is loaded before the initial initialization occurs. not trying to be funny.  if that doesnt make sense I will come up with an example in a little while

Comment: yes please , it doesn't come in initinalization

Comment: ok somewhere you have something that is a variation of `$('.carousel').carousel()` ... whatever that string is, echo it out with your script [at the end], to `reinitialize` the carousel after the script appears on the page.

Comment: maybe use ajax and pass everything you need in from php?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that jquery can work with the eles which was echoed by php. I have just had a test for certain like picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctpoa.png)

and it work. So you need to be sured that the block code of jquery was added after html element was echoed by php

Comment: what is after script?

Comment: is it possible to send me the test you did ?

Comment: @SaraKat sorry i have just left for a while. my test is use blade of laravel. In the template file i divide 2 yield(2 part of code), 1 is content , and the another is after-script. The after-script was put after content to be sure that after that the script was read after the html. Like that https://codeshare.io/alARxB.
If you need full file, give me your email.